# 6 build path entries are missing no eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Ao reinstalar o eclipse e importar meu projeto de volta que foi clonado do gitHub em uma maquina recém formata houve um erro e meu projeto não compila, ele me da um erro sem sentido no console. O que vi foi que algumas bibliotecas não estavam lá, bibliotecas que não pertencem ao meu projeto original talvez bibliotecas do próprio eclipse.

Erro no console: este erro que não faz sentido, pois antes de eu formatar funcionava e não ha nada de errado com a classe resource manager

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at br.sp.mogi.imperiocongelados.res.ResourceManager.initialize(ResourceManager.java:142)
    at br.sp.mogi.imperiocongelados.Principal.main(Principal.java:16)
```

Icone de exclamação vermelho ao lado do nome do projeto
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Build path com as 6 bibliotecas que ele acusa estarem faltando
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu excluir as bibliotecas que estão faltando ele volta a compilar, contudo não acho que seria a solução mais adequada excluir bibliotecas que nem sei pra que servem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geralmente este erro acontece quando o eclipse perde a referência das bibliotecas, tente remover essas bibliotecas que estão sinalizadas com erro e adicioná-las novamente.

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: E onde eu acho essas bibliotecas novamente? para eu poder importa-las de volta

Comment: Grande parte você pode encontrar no aqui https://mvnrepository.com/ o restante terá que buscar no Google.

Comment: Sim, eu achei que o eclipse teria um um backup dessas bibliotecas, mas eu já estou procurando elas. Me ajudou bastante, obrigado